# Why Flyway programmatic migration succeed but still have Pending status?

Tags: rest, maven, spring-boot, hsqldb, flyway

I just set up Flyway and I have questions :

- 1) I did migration as specified in [official doc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/). Migration data is successful because, tables has been created/scripts executed but when I make `mvn flyway:status`, status is PENDING !!! And also when migration is automatic on startup. The only way to have success status is to make mvn flyway:migrate. (I'm using file HSQL database, not in memory). So `mvn flyway:validate` fail ((2) does `validation` really necessary for migration by the way ?)
- 3) I want to programmatically make migration on demand with REST service (just for testing for the moment) but I find this is contrary to REST principles because I should use a verb method name and no corresponding HttpVerb GET/PUT/...
- In order to avoid migration on application startup, I added this configuration :

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class FlywayConfiguration implements FlywayMigrationStrategy {
      @Override
          public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
          // Do not migrate on startup
      }
  }
  ```

-> 4) Should I use `@Component` instead ? And I didn't see property for this in order to do it more properly than adding this class. (And in documentation, I saw they talked about using a `@Bean`, is that general synonym for `@Component`/`@Configuration` ?)

Thank you,

**Edit** : 1)`mvn flyway:migrate` and `validate` on command line succeed but does not create tables
**Re-Edit** : 1) Solved : this command was execute in the bad module, adding this in general parent pom, it works "fine" :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/airconnectDB</url>
        <user>aLogin</user>
        <password>aPassword</password>
        <locations>
            <location>classpath:db/migration</location>
        </locations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

But this is strange it display me infos as many times as I have modules and for one of the modules, stastus is Future, strange ...